# Upgrade of normal project to Xamarin.Forms project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I had a Xamarin project that was working fine, but it was build some time ago. Now my requirement is to upgrade this project to a Xamarin.Forms project. So I installed the Form nuget package. And then I try build the project. What happen is all api levels setting gone from all the projects. So I increased the api level => min api lavel 19 and compile api level with latest.

After all this I'm getting this error:

> Error 141 Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Mono.Android.Support.v4, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
> File name: 'Mono.Android.Support.v4.dll'
> at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
> at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
> at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute()

I've tried to install the Xamarin.android.supprt.v4.dll from nuget but it made no difference.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I've also updated my the Xamarin for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

*I can only guess, since I can't see your project file.*

This looks like a PCL issue. Xamarin.Forms projects can be either "shared" or "PCL" flavor. The "shared" project has access to the same APIs as your iOS or Android projects. The "PCL" flavor only has access to a subset of the APIs and to make things more complicated - there sub-flavors of PCL.

If you're migrating an existing project to XF I'd say you may be better off with the "shared" flavor. If you're starting new or feel it wouldn't be too much to refactor - use PCL.

It looks like you have a PCL XF project and copied code that tries to use System.IO.File - one of several missing APIs - and you'll have to refactor this API use into a [dependency service](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) or use some [IoC](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/tree/master/src/IOC/XLabs.Ioc) to access it.

In a nutshell you'll create an interface that offers the file functionality you need (save, load, delete...), implement that interface in your respective iOS/Android/Win project or even better - shared project - and use IoC to instantiate the interface in XF project. For examples see how [MediaService](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/Samples/XLabs.Sample/ViewModel/CameraViewModel.cs) from [XLabs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XLabs.Forms/) is used